# Annihilator for another Annihilator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a Banach Space, $ Y\subset X $ a closed subspace, $X^*$ is the dual space to  X and  $N_Y$  = {$f\in X^* | f(Y)=0$ for any y∈ Y } ( The set $N_Y$ is called annulator for Y). Prove that 
Y={y∈ X | f(y)=0 for any  f ∈ $ N_Y $} , i.e that Y is annulator for $N_Y$.

I did it till this : 
If $f, g ∈ N_Y $ and λ ∈ R, then (f + g)(y) = 0 and (λf)(y) = 0 for
all x ∈ Y, so $ f + g ∈ N_Y $ and $λf ∈ N_Y$. It follows that $N_Y $is a vector
space. If $f_n → f$ in norm and $f_n ∈ N_Y$, then
$f(x) = limn→∞f_n(y) = 0$ for every y ∈ Y,
so f ∈ $N_Y$, meaning that $N_Y$ is closed.

I don't know it ok or not. What Next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of Hahhn Banach, if the annihilator of $N_Y$ contains $x$ which is not in $Y$, $M=N\oplus Vect(x)$ is closed and the linear function defined on $M$ by $f(x)=1, f(Y)=0$ is continuous since its kernel is closed, it can be extended to $X$ by Hahn Banach, denote by $g$ this extension, $g\in N_Y$ contradiction since $g(x)\neq 0$. This implies that  the annihilator of $N_Y$ is contained in $Y$, $Y$ is contained in the annihilator of $N_Y$ by definition.

Comment: Sorry, Not clear at all. Could you please explain in detail ?

Comment: what is not clear ?

Comment: I am not clear how to proceed ?

Comment: Let $N_Y=\overline{span}$ and suppose $x∉N_Y$. Now consider the normed space $X/N_Y$ and the natural projection $ π:X→X/N_Y $. Then take $V={α(x+N_Y)∣α∈C}⊂X/M$. Note that $ ‖x+N_Y‖>0 $ so we can define a functional $g:V→ℂ:α(x+N_Y)↦α‖x+N_Y‖$. Note that $‖g‖=1$. Now extend g by the Hahn Banach theorem to $g:X/N_Y→ℂ $. Finally we can define $f=1‖x+N_Y‖g∘π$. Notice that $π(y)=0$ for all $y∈Y$ so $f(y)=0$ for all $y∈N_Y$. But $f(x)=1 $by construction.
Is it OK ?